# I'm having issues with Javascript Progress Bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to get Javascript change html text when the progress bar gets to 100% and to not run at all (progress bar) if the value of a html element = 0  but it seems there's an error somewhere because its not working.

Here's my code:

```js
var i = 0;

function move() {
  if (i == 0) {
    i = 1;
    
    var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
    var width = 10;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
    var get = document.getElementById("btn").innerHTML('5');
    
    function frame() {
      if (width >= 100) {
        get();
        i = 0;
        frame();

      } else {
        width++;
        elem.style.width = width + "%";
        elem.innerHTML = width  + "%";
        document.getElementById("btn").innerHTML('1000');

      }
    }
  }
}

function trade() {
  var add = document.getElementById("btc");
  
  if (add == 0) {
    alert("blance is 0")
  } else {
    move();
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
  <body>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-7">
        <h3> Total:</h3>
      </div>
      
      <div>
        <h5 id="btc"><strong>0 </strong></h5>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <h3>Balance:</h3>
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <h5 id="btn">0</span></strong></h5>
    </div>
    <div id="myBar" style="width: 1%; background-color: red; line-height: 30px; color: black;">0%</div>

    <br>
    
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="move(); trade();" > Click to Start trade</button>

  </body>
</html>
```

I know my code is kind of messed up. Please, Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I somewhat changed your code but I believe this is what you want. You can spike the values in `random` to change the rate of the winnings. I also changed the `Total` field and named it to `Profit`, I wasn't sure what was the purpose of this field.

I will try to point out some mistakes that I've noticed.

1. You can define a function inside another function but the way you define and execute them is different. Check [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-nested-functions/) for more info and examples.
2. When you read values from HTML you need to convert them into numbers in order to do any mathematical operations with them I used the function `parseInt(text)` to do that.
3. `innerHTML` is a property not a function, so if you want to change that property you need to assign it a value by using an `=` sign, like this `document.getElementById("btc").innerHTML = 0`. Thankfully you don't need to convert a number into a string to store it in this property.

That's it, I hope this to be more helpful than confusing.

```js
function move() {
  var i = 0;

  if (i == 0) {
    
    var loadingBar = document.getElementById("myBar");
    var width = 1;
    
    var initialProfit = document.getElementById("btc").innerHTML = 0;
    var initialBalance = document.getElementById("btn").innerHTML = 1000;
    
    setInterval( function() {
      var profit = parseInt( document.getElementById( 'btc' ).innerHTML );
      var balance = parseInt( document.getElementById( 'btn' ).innerHTML );
      var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (50 - (-35))) + (-35);
      
      if (width >= 100) {
      
        i = 0;
        return;
        
      } else {
        width++;
        loadingBar.style.width = width + "%";
        loadingBar.innerHTML = width  + "%";
        document.getElementById( 'btn' ).innerHTML = balance + random;
        
        document.getElementById( 'btc' ).innerHTML = profit + random;
      }
    }, 200 );

  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
  <body>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-7">
        <h3> Profit:</h3>
      </div>
      
      <div>
        <h5 id="btc">0</h5>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <h3>Balance:</h3>
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <h5 id="btn">0</span></strong></h5>
    </div>
    <div id="myBar" style="width: 1%; background-color: red; line-height: 30px; color: black;">0%</div>

    <br>
    
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="move();" > Click to Start trade</button>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what i've been looking for.

Comment: @PriscaChidimma I am glad I could help!